# How to set multiple cookies with PHP setcookie function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a login page so I need to store two cookies in the client computer. One is for the user name and other one is for the user id. I used javascript XHTTP request to send this data.

I can set the first cookie but I can't set the second. Below is my code :

```
   //geting user login details

   $userDetails = json_decode($_POST["m"]);
   $userEmail =$userDetails->useremail;
   $userPassword = $userDetails->userPassword;
    //Create Connection
    $conn = new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Check Connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection Failed :".$conn->connect_error);
       }

     //selecting data from database

     $sql = "SELECT  email, userPassword, name, User_ID FROM User_Details" 
      ;
     $result = $conn->query($sql);


     //checking the user details

      while($details = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        if($userEmail==$details["email"]&&$userPassword===$details["userPassword"]) {
          session_start();

          $name = $details["name"];
          $userId = $details["User_ID"];

          $_SESSION["name"] = $name;

          $cookieName = "userName";
          $coockieUserId = "UserId";

          setcookie ($cookieName,$name, time() + 86400, "/");
          setcookie ($cookieUserId,$userId, time() + 86400, "/");
          echo  $userId; 
          break;  
     $conn->close();
    }
```

I can find the first cookie(user name) with `Document.cookie();`
but I can't find the second one. But you can see i have put a code 
`echo $userId;`
so in chrome debugger I can see the user Id echoed.

Can you please help me to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: How do you know the cookie is not set? Do note that if you're setting it in ajax call, then they are not going to be visible to the original page until it reloads.

Comment: There's a typo: you're setting `$coockieUserId`. That code shouldn't even run as-is. Besides that there's no need for a second cookie, you can use php's `$_SESSION` object to store arbitrary data that is retained between scripts. Also, no need to fetch the entire user table, then manually compare. Use a `WHERE` query instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I use chrome debugging tol to check whether cookie is set or not. First cookie can see. Second one can't see.

Comment: Chris G thanks for advice. I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is undefined

You've defined

```
 $coockieUserId = "UserId";
```

and are using

```
setcookie ($cookieUserId,$userId, time() + 86400, "/");
```

Comment: I'm not clear about that?                                                                                $cookieUserId````                                                                                                    
is the name of cookie.          
 ````$userId````                                                                                                             
 is the value of the cookie.

Comment: The variable is you are defining is $coockieUserId and you're using $cookieUserId.There is a spelling error here

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Thanks a lot.